# Count ssh ControlMaster connections

Tags: ssh, connection

I am trying to debug a slow ssh connection problem and I would like to figure out if `ControlMaster` is working properly. To that end I need to know the total connections to the remote server. How can I reliably figure that out?

Comment: Run `ps -fe` on the remote system and count the number of `sshd` instances? One of them is probably listening for new connections, while each of the others is handling a connected session.

Comment: Is there a way to do it on the client side?